# Creating a Wear AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I've several comments in my android wear applications which says that my app doesn't look good on two devices:

ZenWatch and Sony SmartWatch3.
I've gathered DPI and resolution of both:
ZenWatch - 320x320 round 278dpi 1.63 inches
SmartWatch3 - 320x320 square 283dpi 1.6 inches.

Now, I'm trying to run the APP further than the basic emulator. However, there are just two configurations I can use:
[image]

I've tried editing it's config files, with no luck.
in config files I couldn't manage to find screen size. Just DPI and looks like any configuration changed, is ignored.

The following is all the configuration I've found interesting:

```
hw.lcd.density=240
```

No screen size, no resolution. Just lcd density, which for me looks like DPI, but now I'm not sure. So I cannot mimic any of the two above mentioned devices.

Any tips about this?

Edit 6 June 2015:
I cannot run the device I configurated:
[image]

As you can see, a yellow warning is shown, which says the following
[image]

So I'm not able to run any device I created.

Comment: what is your system configuration? Any error at `Console` >`Android` ?

Comment: @maveň what do you mean with system configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Button of **AVD Manager**, then click **Create Virtual Device...**, then click **New Hardware Profile**, then you can in the new window customize settings of a hardware, like **Device Name**, **Device Type**, **Screen(ScreenSize, Resolution)**, **Memory**, **Input**, **Supported Device states**, **Camera** and **Sensors**. 
[image]

After finishing these, you can select **this Hardware Profile** to create your **AVD**.

Comment: Hello, have you actually tried creating it? I attach a screenshot on the main post.

Comment: Of course, I created one successfully. According information you provided, it seems that your sdk is not up to date. Maybe you need to updated you development environment, like SDK, Android Studio and avd images.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If I understood you correctly, you need to click on the "New Hardware Profile" button on the buttom left corner and then you can change the size of the screen, it's resolution and more.

Comment: I tried creating one with a different screen size in pixels and inches, however the APP appearance was still correct. So I guess I couldn't manage to reproduce the bad appearance. I state some comments in Google Play "Doesn't work on asus zen All the colors overlap and couldn't use.", " This game on Sony Smartwatch 3 (square screen)  is broken. The buttons are all weirdly placed on the screen. Too bad :c"

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán It's your app? Because if it does, you can exclude these devices from downloading the app.

Comment: It is, but I don't want to exclude. I want to fix it :D

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of answering some other users... What I've been actually facing, was that there's a different DPI used in an AsusZenwatch on 4.4W and 5.1.1... Weird but true. Be sure to test on both APIs